# Converting Oracle Blob Insert into SQL varbinary with C#

Tags: c#, oracle, t-sql

Trying to convert an application from a Oracle Database to a T-SQL database. I'm having issues understanding the conversion. Could someone please explain or show me how this would look like if you were using T-SQL and not Oracle. Below is the original code and below that is my very bad attempt at trying to understand and convert it.

```
 OracleBlob blob = null;

    try
    {
        using (OracleConnection cnnOra = new OracleConnection("OraConnection"))
        {
            cnnOra.Open();
            OracleTransaction tnsOra = cnnOra.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                string strID = Session["ID"].ToString();
                string strUser = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"].ToUpper();

                OracleCommand cmdUpdateCurrent = new OracleCommand("update USER_1999_FILES set IS_CURRENT = 'N' where ID = " + strID, cnnOra);
                cmdUpdateCurrent.Transaction = tnsOra;
                cmdUpdateCurrent.ExecuteNonQuery();

                OracleCommand cmdInsBlob;
                cmdInsBlob = new OracleCommand("insert into USER_1999_FILES (ID,FILE_DATA,DATE_LOADED,LOADED_BY,IS_CURRENT,ROLE) values (" + strID + ",:BlobData, sysdate,'" + strUser + "','Y','" + strRole + "')", cnnOra);
                cmdInsBlob.Transaction = tnsOra;
                blob = new OracleBlob(cnnOra);
                blob.Erase();
                byte[] bFile = Convert.FromBase64String(JDSSignAjax1.SignedPDFBase64);
                blob.Write(bFile, 0, bFile.Length);
                cmdInsBlob.Parameters.Add("BlobData", OracleDbType.Blob);
                cmdInsBlob.Parameters["BlobData"].Value = blob;
                cmdInsBlob.ExecuteNonQuery();
                tnsOra.Commit();
            }
```

My attempt:

```
//Not sure what OracleBlob blob = null; is.
    //OracleBlob blob = null;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection cnnOra = new SqlConnection("SqlConnection"))
        {
            cnnOra.Open();
            SqlTransaction tnsOra = cnnOra.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                string strID = Session["ID"].ToString();
                string strUser = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"].ToUpper();

                SqlCommand cmdUpdateCurrent = new SqlCommand("update USER_1999_FILES set IS_CURRENT = 'N' where ID = " + strID, cnnOra);
                cmdUpdateCurrent.Transaction = tnsOra;
                cmdUpdateCurrent.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlCommand cmdInsBlob;
                cmdInsBlob = new SqlCommand("insert into USER_1999_FILES (ID,FILE_DATA,DATE_LOADED,LOADED_BY,IS_CURRENT,ROLE) values (" + strID + ",:BlobData, sysdate,'" + strUser + "','Y','" + strRole + "')", cnnOra);
                cmdInsBlob.Transaction = tnsOra;
                //This is the part I get confused i'm not excactly sure what OracleBlob is or what it is doing. 
                blob = new OracleBlob(cnnOra);
                blob.Erase();
                byte[] bFile = Convert.FromBase64String(JDSSignAjax1.SignedPDFBase64);
                blob.Write(bFile, 0, bFile.Length);
                cmdInsBlob.Parameters.Add("@BlobData", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = blob;
                cmdInsBlob.Parameters["@BlobData"].Value = blob;
                cmdInsBlob.ExecuteNonQuery();
                tnsOra.Commit();
            }
```

Comment: You need to post the OracleBlob class.  If you right click the OracleBlob and select "definition" you will find the source code.

Comment: Have you checked  the docs? Using blobs with ADO.NET and SQL Server is definitely documented, with examples for writing not only full blobs but using streaming and file storage

Comment: @jdweng Alright added. Just curious would I still be using OracleBlob when I am doing the converting since it is apart of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types?

Comment: Why are you looking at Oracle code *at all* when you want to use SQL Server? BLOB storage is product-specific and one product's features can be *very* different from another's

Comment: Check the examples in [SQL Server Binary and Large-Value data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sql-server-binary-and-large-value-data).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is why I am asking how to convert. I'm trying to get away from Oracle. I have been following https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48619/Reading-and-Writing-BLOB-Data-to-Microsoft-SQL-or in trying to understand how to convert it.

Comment: Don't convert. Read the examples in the docs. The code is very different, with almost 90% of the code gone

Comment: Besides, since you're working with files, FILESTREAM storage may be preferable, in which case you can work with Stream objects directly

Comment: Why did you define only `BlobData` as parameter? Do it for all parameters!